# What does "shortage" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have been trying to translate an [article](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018) about wearable smart watches. The meaning of "shortage" in the text below is unclear to me: Does it mean **lack of quantity** or **lack of quality** or **lack of facilities** ?

> There is no **shortage** of wearable gear out there, and really what I’m
>   writing about here is the latest crop of smartwatches, most of which
>   run on Android Wear. In the grand scheme, I know it is but a portion
>   of what many of us may use, be it Jawbone’s UP, or Fitbit, or
>   Samsung’s Tizen powered Galaxy Gear, and for me, it really comes down
>   to a single issue. As I thought about that single issue though, I
>   examined other factors that leave me feeling pensive about what lies
>   ahead.

Comment: here, it's *lack of quantity*.  Shortage is an economic term that indicates that there isn't enough supply to meet the demand at a particular price.

Comment: Or possibly _lack of options_

Comment: @Adam is correct as well.  In this context it's saying that there are *many* different types of wearable gear out there=- I.e., there is a large quantity of wearables out there.

Answer (score 2):

As an avid reader of technology articles, I strongly agree with Adam and disagree with Jim. The statement "*There is no shortage of*" can be clarified by assuming the **context** of the writer.

As a writer on smartwatches, the writer has familiarity with the assortment of options available. I would assume that the writer is a **reviewer**, meaning he/she is writing about smartwatches based on his/her hands-on experience with each of these. I instantly visualized the writer (as I tend to do) surrounded at a desk by an assortment of smartwatches...

With this in mind, it's clear that the "*shortage*" refers to the variety of smartwatches available for purchase, unless there's something else to the article talking about the quality and/or facilities related to smartwatches.

Answer (score 1):

The negation makes it irrelevant: There is ample quantity, quality, *and* facilities, as applicable. No matter what you're looking for in wearable gear, it's out there.